React-Native: Why does something show on expo-Go but not on webview?
Why does something show on expo-Go but not on webview?
Once I changed return <Text>{data.id}</Text>:: Line_17 into return <Text>blablabla</Text>,
it shows on both webview and expo go, but I want to get my API so I have to use {data.id}. However, it only shows on expo go after changing it.

After changing it (preview):
Expo-Go view
Web-view(browser)

Here is my code (part of it):
app.js
function HomeScreen() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const mojang_url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(mojang_url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => setData(json))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [])

  const getContent = () => {
    if (loading) {
      return <Text>Loading...</Text>
    } else {
      return <Text>{data.id}</Text> // <<<<--------- :: Line 17
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.self}>
        <Text>test self</Text>
      </View>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.player}>
          <Text>Player_1</Text>
          <Text>{getContent()}</Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  )
}


